# How to make wp_insert_post_data and sessions work together properly?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to process the post content before saving it to database and inform user if there was any error. I'm using wp_insert_post_data filter, sessions and admin_notices, since it seems to be the only simple solution to throw the error message to edit screen in admin panel after publishing. However, I ran into strange problem - the code seems to run twice, so when I have:

```
function notices(){
if(!empty($_SESSION['notices'])) print  $_SESSION['notices'];
unset ($_SESSION['notices']);}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'notices' );

add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'processdata', '99', 2);
function processdata($data) {
$processed_content = filterthis($data['post_content']);
if($processed_content!='error') {
$data['post_content'] = $processed_content;
$_SESSION['notices'] .= '<div class="updated"><p>Everything is ok</p></div>';
return $data;
} else {
$_SESSION['notices'] .= '<div class="error"><p>Something went wrong</p></div>';
return $data;}
```

I receive two messages. I've made some tests and it seems that first is for content that is to be saved in database and second for the "old" content (already saved). For example: if previous content was "wrong" and the one to be saved is "ok", the first message is "ok" and second "error" and so on. However, all messages are generated on the same time (so this is not some kind of caching problem, I suppose).
What is even more strange for me, is that if I use this simple code:

```
add_filter ('wp_insert_post_data', 'filterthis', '99', 2);
function filterthis($data){
$date = date('H:i:s');
$_SESSION['my_admin_notices'] .= '<div class="updated"><p>This is a message from '.$date.'</p></div>';
$data['post_content'] .= $date;
return $data;
}
```

I get also two messages, but only one piece of timing data appended to post content - identical to the one delivered by the first message. So it seems like the code runs twice, but only for the first time it saves the content to database... I'm totally confused after seven hours of googling and reading Codex. Maybe the solution is trivial, but I'm not really a PHP programmer, just learning it for a while, so I would be very glad if someone here could help me.

Comment: If you just want to validate post data, and show an error message if necessary, you shouldn't need to use session. See my answer to this earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152315/wordpress-how-displaying-custom-error-message-in-wp-insert-post-data/6156322#6156322

Comment: Thanks, I've read your post earlier, when I was looking for the method to provide user with custom error message. However, using session seemed to me a little more straightforward. Now I think I was wrong;) I will implement your solution into my script for sure. Nevertheless, this session question is still driving me crazy...

Comment: @richard-m I've tested your solution and guess what - I have the same problem... If I publish the content with error, "error" message appears, but then if I save it once again, this time ok, error message stays. I must press "Update" once more to get rid of it. My functions.php code is: [pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/JPfvkGaS). I'm trying to add sections to post content, function sectionize is returning the array with [0]error and [1]section-tag-stripped content on error and string sectionized content on ok (proper heading tags order etc.). Do you have any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: @richard-m One more notice - I put date('G i s') into the message body and it differs, so it seems that second error message is generated during the second ("ok") save, although it shouldn't (error condition is not met and content is formatted properly). I've got plain Wordpress 3.2.1 install here, without any plugins turned on.

Comment: Ah, looks like it's something to do with the Wordpress revision system (which I have disabled). You can probably just add a clause to your condition to check if a revision is being saved: `if ($data['post_type'] !== 'revision' && is_array($processed_content)) {`

Comment: @richard-m Thank you! Indeed, disabling revisions in wp_config solved my problem. Looks like I still have much to learn about Wordpress. You are my hero!:)

Answer (score 0):

I have also face the same problem when I made custom field validation before publish the post. Also when update the published post this filter gives strange behavior. so I have decide to go for client side validation.

Which is very simple DOM operation.

Please refer following link if you want to use client side validation.

http://greatindiaclub.oliwy.net/?p=1101